# Solving a java riddle

Tags: java, class, oop, if-statement

I'm given class `A` and class `C`, and I'm supposed to write class `B` which makes the output of the main in class `C` always `successful!` .
Sine there is a random boolean variable, I get a good result only when it's false, when it's true I don't get an output.
I'm not allowed to make any changes in class `A` or `C`.

I understand that the problem is in the third `if` in class `C`, but what changes I can make in class `B` to prevent from getting into this `if`?

```
    public class A {

    public String foo(String s) {
        return s;
    }
}

    public class B extends A {


    public A getA(boolean flag){
        A a = new A();
        if (flag){

            return(a);
        }
        else{
            return (a);
        }

    }

}


    package sw1.riddles.second;

import java.util.Random;

public class C {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = args[0];
        B b = new B();
        Random random = new Random();
        boolean randomBool = random.nextBoolean();
        A a = b.getA(randomBool);

        if (randomBool) {
            if (!input.equals(a.foo(input))) {
                return;
            }
        } else {
            if (!(input+input).equals(a.foo(input))) {
                return;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("success!");
    }
}
```

Comment: `A` is not final, so you can override it with an anonymous subclass in `B.getA` which depends on your flag. What's the purpose here? Looks like a really strange school assignment.

Comment: No need for an anonymous subclass. Just override foo() in B and return `this` if flag is false.

Comment: You are not allowed to reach either `return`. So a.foo(input) must return either `input` (`randomBool`)  or `input+input` (`!randomBool`). So `b.getA(randomBool)` must return different things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class B should be as follows:

```
public class B extends A{
    public String foo(String s){
        return s+s;
    }

    public A getA(boolean flag){
        if (flag){
            A a = new A();
            return(a);
        }
        else{
            B b = new B();
            return (b);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe solution:

```
public class B extends A {


    public A getA(boolean flag){
        if (flag){ //true -> usual A with foo == input
            return new A(); //or this
        }
        //false-> custom A with foo == input + input
        return new A(){
            @Override
            public String foo(String s) {
                return s+s;
            }
        };
    }
}
```